# Second Firefox volume control in Windows mixer

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox, audio

Since I updated to Firefox 56.0 (64-Bit) there is a second volume control in the Windows mixer called "Firefox" (the first one is called "Mozilla Firefox"). The Problem is, that this control does not show up on Firefox start. It appears when I play a video or something else playing music. It then stays there as long as the music plays. But when I close the video, it disappears after some time. The next time I open a video, it appears again, but is at maximum volume.

How can I remove the second volume control or at least make it store the last volume I've set?

Running Firefox 56.0 (64-Bit) under Windows 10 with Realtek High Definition Audio.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Realtek control panel. If you only have 2 speakers make sure the front left and right are not selected. If they are turn them off and the problem will go away